# Resource call to unreachable resource freezes UI

Tags: angularjs

We have the following service:

```
app.factory('myService', function($resource) {
   return $resource("resources/myServiceUri", {param1: "foo"}, {
      get: {method: "GET", isArray: true}
    });
});
```

On page load our application calls the service like this:

```
myService.get({},function(result) {
    model.myServicesModel = result;
    console.log("if there are network problems the control goes here");
});
```

This works perfectly when background is running and connections are ok. But if for a reason or another background service cannot connect to the database it's using the resource call will return a response with error code 500. This is still ok, but seems this service call return a huge amount of resource objects each containing a single character from the exception thrown by background service.

As you see, we're not using error callback at all, but even if we did the control goes to success callback when this problem occurs.

Is there a good way to handle this? Can we somehow bypass the responses that return with error code 500?

Problem may be solved by making a 'preresource call' that only returns http headers for this same call, but are there better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the right solution, but adding an empty error callback should solve the problem.

```
myService.get({},function(result) {
  model.myServicesModel = result;
  console.log("if there are network problems the control goes here");
}, function() {
  //error
});
```

With this callback, your result won't be assigned to your model. If you add parameter(s) to the callback function, you can also  know the error status and headers and display useful informations to the user about the error.

Comment: Adding error callback doesn't help here since it won't get called anyway. Also the success callback for resource call of type GET doesn't return status code by default. I did edit the angular-resource.js and add the status code, but knowing it doesn't help in this case since the browser already freezes when the control enters success callback.

Comment: and the problem isn't setting result to my model - the damage is done when the errorneous REST result is fetched. Another thing to note is that angularjs seems to handle every letter in the exception thrown by background service as a independent json result object. I think this problem should be solved by adding more catch clauses in background and returning a JSON object with error message to REST service